# Convertir numero decimales a binario

Tags: java, array

Tengo el código donde ingreso una cierta cantidad de números que van del 0 al 9 estos números los  almaceno en un arreglo de tipo int después tengo que convertir cada uno de los números que hay en el arreglo en binario de 4 cifras es decir si en el arreglo se encuentra un 2 su equivalente en binario seria 0010 si ingreso el 4 su equivalente seria 0100 etc. Ya cuento con el código que me transforma  los números a binario pero el problema es que si ingreso el 2 solo me da 10 y no se como agregar los ceros que faltan dejo mi código aquí:

public class Fecha {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String f_h;
    String fecha_hora;
    fecha_hora = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la fecha dd/mm/aa y la hora");
    f_h = fecha_hora.replaceAll("/|\\s|:", "");
    int[] digitos = new int[14];
    String cad;
    int ent;
    char[] caracteres = f_h.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++) {
        cad = Character.toString(caracteres[i]);
        ent = Integer.parseInt(cad);
        digitos[i] = ent;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < digitos.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(digitos[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 0; i < digitos.length; i++) {
        String binario = Integer.toBinaryString(digitos[i]);
        System.out.println(binario);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una solución que encontré en [Left padding a String with Zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros)

```java
String s = Integer.toBinaryString(10); //Convert decimal to binary
int p = 4; //preferred length
for (int g = 0, j = s.length(); g < p - j; g++, s = "0" + s);
System.out.println(s);
```

En el link hay varias soluciones ve cual se adapta mas a tus requerimientos

Answer (score 1):

Encontré una posible solución a mi problema es la siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < digitos.length; i++) {
             binario = Integer.toBinaryString(digitos[i]);
            if (digitos[i] <= 1) {
                System.out.print("000" + binario);
            } else if ((digitos[i] > 1)&&(digitos[i]<4)) {
                System.out.print("00" + binario);
            }else if((digitos[i] >=4)&&((digitos[i] <8))){
                System.out.print("0" + binario);
            }else if(digitos[i]>=8){
                System.out.print(binario);
            }
```

de esta manera agrega la cantidad de 0 que sean necesarios

Comment: Esta solución funciona pero está más complicada de lo que debe ser y no es escalable, te recomendaría mejor la solución de @Juanmhs